# Compare between lists with different lengths?

Tags: python, list, loops, methods

I am comparing two different lists. I need to get the unique elements of each list (those not found in the other list).

Each new list contain what didn't exist in the other.

For example:

```
list1 = ['apple', 'coffee', 'orange', 'sugar']
list2 = ['apple', 'grape', 'orange', 'eggplant', 'pineapple']
```

Expected output

```
new_list1 = ['coffee', 'sugar']
new_list2 = ['grape', 'eggplant', 'pineapple']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Example:

```
list1 = set(['apple', 'coffee', 'orange', 'sugar'])
list2 = set(['apple', 'grape', 'orange', 'eggplant', 'pineapple'])

new_list1 = list(list1 - list2)
new_list2 = list(list2 - list1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the unique elements from each list and not have them in seperate lists use the XOR operator for sets and not difference:

```
list1 = ['apple', 'coffee', 'orange', 'sugar']
list2 = ['apple', 'grape', 'orange', 'eggplant', 'pineapple']

unique = set(list1) ^ set(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize above solution like this:

```
>>> list(set(list1)-set(list2))
['coffee', 'sugar']
>>> list(set(list2)-set(list1))
['eggplant', 'grape', 'pineapple']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple looping example but not necessarily the most efficient:

```
new_list_1 = [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]
new_list_2 = [item for item in list2 if item not in list1]
```